# IBM BluemixのRetrieve&Rankで継続的に学習し、回答精度を高める仕組みを作る方法

Tags: bluemix, watson-api

以下Webページを参考に、IBM BluemixのRetrieve&Rankサービスを利用して、
問い合わせ応対ができるBotを作成しています。

Qiita BluemixのRetrieve&Rankによる質問応答システムを試してみた
http://qiita.com/VegaSato/items/6d2d03d6a8b42adcf87e

■質問
一度ランカーを学習させた後に、ユーザーの問合せ応対結果をもとに
継続的に学習し、回答精度を高める仕組みはどのように構築したら良いでしょうか。

■想定
継続的に学習するようなR&RサービスのAPIは見当たらなかったため、
ユーザーの問合せ応対結果から、GroundTruthファイルをチューニング※し、
再度ランカーのトレーニングを行うような処理を定期的に行う必要があるかと想定しています。

※想定のGTファイルのチューニング内容
・新規の質問があれば、質問・回答のセットを追記
・既存の質問でうまく回答できなかったものがあれば、回答の関連度スコアを増減させる
　（間違って回答したものがあればスコアを下げる、役に立った回答があればスコアを上げる）